# Remote Desktop Services Web Interface desktop pool

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

My goal is to get Remote Desktop Services on Windows Server 2008 R2 running with a Desktop pool (IE When a user connects, he is directed to 1 of many Remote Desktop servers with the lowest load).

It's my understand that in 2008 R2, this is referred to as a Connection Broker. I have installed it all, but im unable to figure out how to make the Web interface have the option "desktop".

Does anybody know how to add a shortcut to the desktop pool?

I have made several attempts to make this happen, my current attempt is built around the following [guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772245.aspx), still unsuccessful.

This solution will be accessed via the internet, so the users will NOT have direct acccess to the terminal servers. ( So it reqiures Terminal server Gateway )

Answer (score -1):

This guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd883265(v=ws.10).aspx outlines the requirements and steps needed to publish RDS desktop pools to one or more RDS Web Access servers while having a RDS Connection Broker manage the connections. It's the guide you should be following, not the one you linked to.

Comment: I think that link referes to Virtual desktops ( IE 1 virutal machine pr user) ?

Im thinking more traditional RDP/citrix

Comment: Then you're not talking about a desktop pool.

Comment: It could very much be that im confusing the words used for the different tech. If you know the correct description let me know :)

Comment: You just want to publish RDS over RD Web Applications it sounds like. You can do that natively, you just put in the name of the connection broker. Simple as that.

Comment: Im pretty sure its simple, its a case of me having worked so much on it that im blind.